# Ошибка при установке Composer через терминал в Atom

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, composer, atom

Для создания виртуального сервера использую MAMP, а в качестве редактора кода Atom.

Перекинул папку htdocs и установил терминал platformio-ide-terminal в Atom. Начинаю установку Composer непосредственно в самом терминале, как выдает ошибки следующего типа:

php : Имя "php" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой
программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, по
сле чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1

- php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (php:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Команды для установки Composer использовал следующие:

php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"

php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '756890a4488ce9024fc62c56153228907f1545c228516cbf63f885e036d37e9a59d27d63f46af1d4d07ee0f76181c7d3') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"

php composer-setup.php

php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

Прошу объяснить саму проблему и помочь найти решение

Comment: А сам PHP глобально установлен на Вашей машине? Откройте терминал и напишите `php -v`

Comment: Ввёл, все та же ошибка. Сам PHP только пытался установить, в системе указал путь непосредственно к самой папке PHP. Пробовал снова - все тщетно.

Comment: Какой еще папке PHP, с вашим кодом что ли? Если вы работаете с XAMPP/MAMP и другими, то используйте их консоль для запуска php исполняемого файла, а не стороннюю или системную консоль так как они на настраивают вашу ОС и пути к нему.

Comment: О, было такое, пришлось устанавливайть компосер напрямую  без пыхи

Comment: Николай, спасибо за совет, наверно уж придётся так и решать проблему. А другой способ какой-нибудь существует? Вы так и решили эту проблему у себя?